# Is it possible to parse Date-time in BigQuery beyond Microseconds?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datetime-format

So, in BigQuery SQL the following Statement Works:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456Z")
```

However, this one doesn't:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456789Z")
```

It produces "Invalid timestamp: '2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456789Z'"

It appears that the standard BigQuery SQL TIMESTAMP function does not parse date-time beyond microseconds.

Is there a best practice or other elegant way to deal with that?
I can think of writing my own parser, but that seems like an overkill...

Edit: Using the PARSE_TIMESTAMP function

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E6SZ", "2022-09-16T14:07:28.123456Z")
```

Also works fine, but

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E7SZ", "2022-09-16T14:07:28.1234567Z")
```

Does not.

Edit: Currently it seems like this feature does not exist.
[Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296986142) is a feature request for the same...

Answer (score 0):

For microseconds, you have to do this and then it will work fine:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP("2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456Z") => produces => 2023-07-20 12:32:36.238140 UTC
```

(you had extra digits in your sample so you sample does not work)

If you wish to extract microseconds from above, this will work:

```
 SELECT extract(microsecond from TIMESTAMP("2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456Z")) => produces => 238140
```

Please check allowed 'PART' values: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#current_timestamp

It only goes up to microseconds as lowest granularity. You can not use any native GBQ functionality to go beyond that.

Comment: I think he wants 238140463 as his microsecond output not 238140

Comment: Exactly, the problem only arises for more than 6 decimal digits, for 6 all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in BQ, you cant go more than 6 fractions of microseconds in the default timestamp function. So thats why. I think you have to create your own parser, but it can be done using parse_timestamp method to create your own custom rule

```
WITH input AS (SELECT "2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456789Z" AS timestampStr)

SELECT
  timestampStr,
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%E3*Z', timestampStr) AS parsedTimestamp
FROM input;
```

Comment: Does the code work for you? For me it produces:
"Failed to parse input string "2023-07-20T12:32:36.123456789Z""

Comment: I do not have access to bigquery environment now, thats why I did it hypothetically, let me see if I can get access and try it for you.